# How to share data between two HTML pages using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Im learning AngularJS (for an old project). I have 2 pages.

Page 1: Lists all the records with an 'a' tag to take the user to an edit page.
Page 2: Is the edit page where the user can edit details and then save the record.

On page 1 i have (Short version of the code)

```
 <thead>
      <tr>
        <td>
           <label title="Name">Name</label>
         </td>
  </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="c in vm.logData">
        <td>
         <a id="Edit" ng-href="customers/edit/{{c.Id}}">Edit</a>
            </td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

This works well and shows a list of custs. When they click edit they **go to a new page**. This page allows the user to **edit their details** and save the data back to a database.

The edit page HTML is

```
<div ng-controller="CustomerControllerEdit as vm">
<input type="text" title="Name" ng-model="vm.customer.Name"/>
</div>
```

Now as you can probably tell i have two different controllers

CustomerController - loads the list data.

CustomerController also has the method vm.customer(c.Id) method which loads the data for a single customer

Code for CustomerController

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module("myMod")
        .controller("CustomerController",
            function ($routeParams, customerResources, $scope) {
                var vm = this;
                
                function getAllCustomers() {
                    customerResources.getCustomers(vm.customer)
                        .then(function (response) {
 
                        }, function (response) {

                        });
                }
                ....
                ......
```

Code for **CustomerControllerEdit**

```
(function () {
    'use strict';

    angular.module("myMod")
        .controller("CustomerControllerEdit",
            function (customerResources, $scope) {
                var vm = this;

                vm.customer = {
                    CustId: 0,
                    Name: null
                };
                
                var id = $routeParams.id;

                function getCustomer(id) {
                    customerResources.getCustomer(vm.customer.CustId)
                        .then(function (data) {

                        }, function (data) {
                            
                        });
                }

                getCustomer($routeParams.id);
            });
})();
```

So the Edit hyperlink above takes the user to a new Edit page. It loads the record for a single customer but in order for this to work i have had to create two controllers as even if i added a click event to the Edit button like

```
<a id="Edit" ng-href="customers/edit/{{c.Id}}" ng-click="vm.customer(c.Id)">Edit</a>
```

I couldnt load the data in the edit form as i think its one controller for one HTML.

Is there a way to create one controller to use on both HTML forms or have this code with better reusability between the two controllers so when i add additional functionality like Creating a customer i dont have to create a new controller (as the create functionality would be on a new separate page)?